# C# error Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: c#, sql

I am getting the following error and I have been doing a lot of research online to re-solve but i can't seem to find the right answer , A bit of help would be much appreciated.
Many Thanks

> Error:  Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable
>   "@Username@DepartmentName".

```
//DepartmentName and Username are both foreign key from LoginDetails table and Department table

SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PRINCENICHOLAS;Initial Catalog=Kids Company IT Asset;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand sqlcmdLogin = new SqlCommand("Insert into LoginDetails(Username,Password,PrivilegeCode) Values(@Username,@Password,@PrivilegeCode)", cn);

sqlcmdLogin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtEmpFirstName.Text + '.' + txtEmpSurname.Text);
sqlcmdLogin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtEmpPassword.Text);
sqlcmdLogin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrivilegeCode", cboPrivilege.SelectedItem.ToString());
cn.Open();
sqlcmdLogin.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();
//Insert Employee Table
SqlCommand sqlcmdEmp = new SqlCommand("Insert into Employee(FirstName,LastName,DOB,Email,PhoneNumber,JobRole,Username,DepartmentName) Values(@FirstName,@LastName,@DOB,@Email,@PhoneNumber,@JobRole,@Username@DepartmentName)", cn);
sqlcmdEmp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtEmpFirstName.Text);
sqlcmdEmp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtEmpSurname.Text);
sqlcmdEmp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", dtpEmpDOB.Text);
sqlcmdEmp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmpEmail.Text);
sqlcmdEmp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", txtEmpPhone.Text);
sqlcmdEmp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobRole", txtJobRole.Text);
sqlcmdEmp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtEmpFirstName.Text + '.' + txtEmpSurname.Text);
sqlcmdEmp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentName", cboDeptName.SelectedItem.ToString());
cn.Open();      
sqlcmdEmp.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();​
```

Comment: You're missing `,` between the parameters in your sql command......

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with C#.  It should be tagged SQL

Comment: The error message tells you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget to seperate your parameter names with `,` like

```
@Username, @DepartmentName
```

in your `sqlcmdEmp` definition line.

Since you wrote it as `@Username@DepartmentName`, your program expect the exact name of it.

Use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` instead of calling `.Close()` method manually.

```
using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
{
    // Define your command text
    // Add your paramter values
    // Open your connection
    // Execute your query
}
```

Don't store your passwords as a plain text. Read: [Best way to store password in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database)

And don't use `AddWithValue` method. It *may* generate unexpected results sometimes. Use [`.Add()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or it's overloads. Read: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)